How to get Docker Containers to recognise a bind mount to an NFS share
I'm a complete docker beginner. I'm trying to set up a media server using docker.
I have:

A Terramaster NAS (NFS sharing from this, from /mnt/md0/Entertainment, nfs4)
A raspberrypi acting as the docker host (NFS share mounted onto host device at /mnt/Entertainment)

Docker has been set up and the following compose file:
services:
  sonarr:
    image: linuxserver/sonarr
    container_name: sonarr
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - /home/[redacted]/docker/appdata/sonarr:/config
      - /mnt/Entertainment:/data
    ports:
      - 8989:8989
    restart: unless-stopped

  radarr:
    image: linuxserver/radarr
    container_name: radarr
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - /home/[redacted]/docker/appdata/radarr:/config
      - /mnt/Entertainment:/data
    ports:
      - 7878:7878
    restart: unless-stopped

  bazarr:
    image: linuxserver/bazarr
    container_name: bazarr
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - /home/[redacted]/docker/appdata/bazarr:/config
      - /mnt/Entertainment:/data
    ports:
      - 6767:6767
    restart: unless-stopped

  prowlarr:
    image: linuxserver/prowlarr
    container_name: prowlarr
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
    volumes:
      - /home/[redacted]/docker/appdata/prowlarr:/config
    ports:
      - 9696:9696
    restart: unless-stopped

  flaresolverr:
    image: ghcr.io/flaresolverr/flaresolverr:latest
    container_name: flaresolverr
    environment:
      - LOG_LEVEL=info
    ports:
      - 8191:8191
    restart: unless-stopped

  qbittorrent:
    image: linuxserver/qbittorrent
    container_name: qbittorrent
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - WEBUI_PORT=8085
    volumes:
      - /home/[redacted]/docker/appdata/qbittorrent:/config
      - /mnt/Entertainment:/data/torrent
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
      - 6881:6881
      - 6881:6881/udp
    restart: unless-stopped

  watchtower:
    image: containrrr/watchtower
    container_name: watchtower
    command: --cleanup --schedule "0 0 4 * * *"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped

  dozzle:
    image: amir20/dozzle:latest
    container_name: dozzle
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped

  homepage:
    image: ghcr.io/benphelps/homepage:latest
    container_name: homepage
    volumes:
      - /home/[redacted]/docker/appdata/homepage:/config
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: unless-stopped

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce
    container_name: portainer
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/[redacted]/docker/appdata/portainer:/data
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    restart: unless-stopped
 

However, none of the containers that need access to the NFS share are able to do so. When I open up Sonarr, the settings only shows the config file location.
I mounted the NFS share using:
mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.50.182:/mnt/md0 /mnt/Entertainment
The permissions on /mnt/Entertainment share the same PUID as the containers (1000).
I'm not sure what else I should be doing here. Any guidance is appreciated.
